# ReflectionException : Class Admin\AdminBundle\Admin\Entity\Produit does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I use symfony 3 and I try to  manage an admin side  to  manage my products and my commands for my ecommerce website, but I always have the same error :

ReflectionException - Class Admin\AdminBundle\Admin\Entity\Product does not exist

this is my services :

```
services:
app.admin.produit:
    class: Admin\AdminBundle\Admin\ProduitAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Produit" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Admin\AdminBundle\Admin\Entity\Produit
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AdminAdminBundle]]
    public: true


app.admin.commande:
    class: Admin\AdminBundle\Admin\CommandeAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Commande" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Admin\AdminBundle\Admin\Entity\Commande
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AdminAdminBundle]]
    public: true
```

This is my CommandAdmin :

```
    <?php
    namespace Admin\AdminBundle\Admin;



    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
       use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
       use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
       use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
       use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;

class CommandeAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('idProduit', 'entity', array('class' => 'Admin\AdminBundle\Entity\Produit'))
            ->add('date')
       ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
       $datagridMapper
            // ->add('idProduit')
            ->add('date')
       ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('idProduit', 'entity', array('class' => 'Admin\AdminBundle\Entity\Produit'))
            ->add('date')
       ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on show action
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
           ->add('idProduit')
           ->add('date')
       ;
    }
}
```

This is my ProduitAdmin :

```
<?php
namespace Admin\AdminBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;

class ProduitAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('quantite')
            ->add('prix')
            ->add('marque')
            ->add('fournisseur')
       ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
       $datagridMapper
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('quantite')
            ->add('prix')
            ->add('marque')
            ->add('fournisseur')
       ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('nom')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('quantite')
            ->add('prix')
            ->add('marque')
            ->add('fournisseur')
       ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on show action
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
           ->add('nom')
           ->add('description')
           ->add('quantite')
           ->add('prix')
           ->add('marque')
           ->add('fournisseur')
       ;
    }
}
```

This is the Stack Trace :

```
ReflectionException:
Class Admin\AdminBundle\Admin\Entity\Produit does not exist

  at vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Controller/CRUDController.php:480
  at ReflectionClass->__construct('Admin\\AdminBundle\\Admin\\Entity\\Produit')
     (vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Controller/CRUDController.php:480)
  at Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController->createAction()
  at call_user_func_array(array(object(CRUDController), 'createAction'), array())
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:153)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:169)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (web/app_dev.php:29)
```

If someone have an idea

Comment: Did you check if ```Admin\AdminBundle\Admin\Entity\Product``` exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty explainable: The class `Admin\AdminBundle\Admin\Entity\Produit` doesn't seem to exists. Take a look at your code, I guess it's not there.

My best guess would be that you mean `Admin\AdminBundle\Entity\Produit` (note the removed `Admin\` subnamespace). The same applies to your `Commande` class specification just below it.

Comment: Yes thks you,  you right . My problem is fixed. thks